# In R, how do I append a new field (or column name) to an existing array?

Tags: r

And when I initialize the new array, would I need every value in this field to be initialized with an actual numerical value?

Comment: What sort of array? An actual R one created by `array()` or something else. It can matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you append the new field will depend on the object you have. Options are given below. If the `length()` of the variable you are trying to append does not equal the number of rows of the object you wish to append to then you will need to fill the new column/variable first with `NA` and then append your variable into the correct elements of the newly created object. For example, with

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2 = LETTERS[1:5])
```

and we want to add a vector `c(1,3,4)` into rows 1, 2, and 5 of a third variable in `df`, then we could do this like so:

```
df$var3 <- NA ## note the single NA is recycled to the correct length
```

Then using subsetting to insert the new data into the correct elements

```
df$var3[c(1,2,5)] <- c(1,3,4)
```

which gives:

```
> df$var3[c(1,2,5)] <- c(1,3,4)
> df
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    A    1
2    2    B    3
3    3    C   NA
4    4    D   NA
5    5    E    4
```

If the variable you wish to append is of the correct length, then you don't need to initialise anything. Use one of the approaches described below to achieve what you want in that case, depending on whether you have a data frame or a matrix.

### Assuming a data frame

If you have a data frame then there are several ways. For example, using

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:10, var2 = LETTERS[1:10])
```

We can do

```
> df$var3 <- letters[1:10]
> df
   var1 var2 var3
1     1    A    a
2     2    B    b
3     3    C    c
4     4    D    d
5     5    E    e
6     6    F    f
7     7    G    g
8     8    H    h
9     9    I    i
10   10    J    j
```

I prefer `transform()`

```
df <- transform(df, var3 = letters[1:10])
```

or the related `within()`

```
df <- within(df, var3 <- letters[1:10]) ## note diff syntax
```

and you can also do

```
df[, "var3"] <- letters[1:10]
```

or

```
df[, 3] <- letters[1:10]
```

but the latter one doesn't produce a variable with the name `"var3"` but instead gets a default name.

You can also use `cbind()` to bind a column to a data frame (also works for matrices). Note that you have to either pass a data frame as the first argument or call the `"data.frame"` method directly otherwise you don't get a data frame as the result:

```
df <- cbind(df, var3 = letters[1:10])
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(var3 = letters[1:10], df)
## note `df2` will have `var3` as the first column here
```

### Assuming a matrix

If you have a matrix, then the options are reduced essentially to using `cbind()`. Using

```
mat <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 2)
```

you can do

```
mat <- cbind(mat, 1:10)
```

The other options don't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you try and add an empty vector to an existing matrix/data frame the vector must be the same length as the other rows/columns in the array. I imagine the best thing to do is to add a vector of NA or NULL values that you can replace as you fill in the data. For example, using the `iris` data from the `datasets` package:

```
iris.new <- data.frame(iris, add = rep(NA, nrow(iris))
```

Then use basic parsing commands to fill in the data.

```
iris.new[13, "add"] <- 100
```

Hope that helps.